# Slideshow transition with blank spot

Tags: jquery, html, slideshow

I have a problem with my slideshow, when it switches to other slide, there is a brief time it is blank but when it reaches the last image and goes to the first again, it doesn't happen, any help?

***Link to the [site](http://moutas.esy.es/example/)***

This is my script code, you can see the html and css in the link above.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var delay = 3000;
    var banners = $('.mySlides');
    var len = banners.length;
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(cycle, delay);

    function cycle() {
        $(banners[i % len]).hide("slide", {
            direction: "left"
        });
        $(banners[++i % len]).show("slide", {
            direction: "right"
        });
    }
});
```

***SOLVED***

Since the images where displaying in block, when the slide, they would go against each other, so I just added `position:absolute` to the images and it turned out alright!

Comment: please send your `js/slide_entrada.js` file i think there is a problem in that

Comment: @Nihal Turns out, that was part of another project of a slideshow, sorry! With or without it, it still happens

Comment: you have `visibility: hidden` on `banners[1]` and `banners[2]`. that rule isn't applied to `banners[0]` so that might be why it shows as expected

Comment: might also try setting `overflow:visible` on your `slideshow-container` class

Comment: @bowl0stu I have that because I want the image to be cut in half without it getting smaller and stranger

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: @bowl0stu Well, I solved the question by adding position absolute to all images.

Comment: @BrunoMoutinho For maintenance and archival purposes, you should consider moving your solution into an answer that you can then mark as having solved your problem.

Comment: Please also update the title. That's a very generic title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the css of the images, added `position: absolute`. The problem was that the images went over each other pushing them out of the div disrupting the slide effect.